# Why we can determine pixel inside outside using (u^2 - v)?

Tags: shader, gpu

Need help to understand [Loop-Blinn 05](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cloop/loopblinn05.pdf),I'm blocked here:

```
During rasterization, the Graphics Processing Unit (GPU) will calculate 
a texture coordinate for each pixel on the interior of the triangle by 
interpolating the texture coordinates of the triangle vertices. 
We determine if the pixel is inside or outside the curve by evaluating
f (u, v) = u^2 − v
```

As title says, Why we can determine pixel inside outside using (u^2 - v) ?

Any Geometry basis i'm missing? Visual explain will be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a curve is of the form `y=x^2`, you know that points below the curve have `y<x^2`, or `x^2-y>0`. Replace x with u, y with v, and decide whether "inside" means above or below the curve... And there is your answer.